# Web, Hybrid or Native? First goal: student timetables, next: anything else the school desires

Tags: c#, java, android, ios, xamarin

I was wondering if you guys could help me figure out what type of app and framework to develop in.
Having done quite a bit of research on my own, has me doubt my choice a lot since it could define a project for a long time.

**My situation:**

As an internship assignment me and 2 other students have to develop a timetable app for the school. The school has a few demands concerning the app.

For instance the app has to be secure (a login functionality is desired. For being able to access account information by law, to be able to e-mail a teacher regarding the upcoming lesson for a student) so there has to be tight security since we're handling personal information.

Since we're interns we have to hand the project over to the developers at the school after our internship is over. The school however, is a Microsoft school. The school only has C# programmers, hence there isn't a lot of experience in-house, when it comes to developing Objective-C. Java is quite similar to C# so it would be less difficult to develop in Android, but there is only 1 developer that has actual experience developing in Java and would therefor be a "single point of failure", which is not desired.

The application has to be able to accomodate multiple apps, if you will. The app would later contain functionality for multiple departments within the school. For these departments Video, the gyroscope, push notifications, e-mail etc. would become things that are needed in the app.

Aside from these demands there are the obvious ones. Which would be speed of the app, and "look and feel" would not be trivial matters.

**My decision**

Preferably I would like to go for Xamarin as the framework. I think it is closest to a native (SDK) app.
A fully native SDK app would be a very close second.

**Others I have considered**

- Titanium
- PhoneGap
- eMobc
- Marmalade

**My request to you**

What would you guys do in my situation. Would you agree with me or do you think a different type of app and framework has to be used here?

Answer (score 2):

A year ago, I had to make the same decision and I went with Xamarin in combination with MvvmCross.

With this you get the best of both worlds:

1. You can develop most of the code in C#
2. You can share nearly all of the code between the applications (this is where MvvmCross comes into play)
3. You still have *native* UIs, i.e. designed in XCode for iPhone or defined in axml for Android.

Speed is not an issue, e.g. on iPhone, the complete .NET code is compiled ahead of time into the native assembly.
Furthermore, the Xamarin SDK is merely a very thin layer over the classes from the phones SDK, giving you the ability to use tutorials that are using Objective-C or Java.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I will take this with me to my final decision. I will however wait for a few more replies (if there are any).